# Delete record in MySQL with php targeting auto_incremented int?

Tags: php, mysql, reserved-words

Why doesnt this delete work to delete the whole record:

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM tblEvents WHERE index = $_GET["id"]';
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
```

Where index is variable of type int, auto_incremented in MySQL?

Comment: Do you get an error when this code runs? If so, what does it say?

Comment: typically dangerous code~you should do some filter before pass something to the sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question php is related, not mysql.
`print $query;` and see.
then refer to php strings syntax, http://php.net/types.string for the proper syntax.

Also, a variable that goes to the query, must be properly prepared, escaped, or, in case of integer value, manually cast to this type,

```
$id=intval($_GET["id"]);
```

or, to make it single line,

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM tblEvents WHERE `index` = '.intval($_GET["id"]);
```

also, index is reserved word that can cause problems too, you can escape it with backticks,

```
`index`
```

but it will be much better if you rename it to just `id`

Comment: better to cast to (int) rather than intvat() - faster and the input should be trusted anyway, no need to extract whatever integers might be in an alphanum string

Comment: There is no word "faster" in such a trifle things. both operators are equal and I prefer most familiar one.

Comment: @Shrapnel general good practice, language constructs actually *are* faster by definition http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/07/02/php-take-advantage-of-language-constructs/

Comment: oh no, don't talk of speed of syntax issues. that's ridiculous. this article is rubbish

Comment: I shall talk of speed no more :)

Answer (score 1):

You should test for delete success with a separate query

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM tblEvents WHERE index = $_GET["id"]';
mysql_query($query, $db);
if( mysql_affected_rows < 1 ) die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Col. Shrapnel is right, you can't use variables directly in a string in single quotes. If you use double quotes around your query, it will work.

EDIT: As Col. Shrapnel said in his comment, in this case you'll also have to change the double quotes in the array offset to single quotes.

Comment: Actually in this very case it wouldn't :)
Associative arrays have it special syntax with double quoted strings.

Comment: You'll have to use single quotes in the array key.

Comment: No, singles won't work too. Either `$_GET[id]` or `{$_GET['id']}` would. that's why I said syntax is "special"

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully you already know this, but you need to secure that `$_GET['id']` so people can't do SQL Injection. Try using the following instead:

```
$query = sprintf('DELETE FROM tblEvents WHERE index = %d',mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
```

This also solves your problem of using a variable in single quotes instead of double quotes.

if you wanted you could also do:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$query = "DELETE FROM tblEvents WHERE index = {$id}";
```

This works too.

Comment: your mysql_real_escape_string can secure nothing.

Comment: According to mysql's site it does: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Read it carefully. It is not a magic word that makes everything "safe". It's part of syntax. You failed to follow all it rules.

Comment: I agree its not the magic wand, but explaining all of that here i thought would be a little too much, especially since i didn't know if he already knew or not. Maybe i should have link for more info the article. Anyway, I literally just mimicked php's example 1. So please tell me what i'm missing, besides like stripslashes or something.

Comment: quotes around value is the thing that missed. it works only together with escaping. most people do quote but forget to escape, but you do opposite :)